# Как получить id сообщения в телеграмм боте

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить id сообщения, переданного методом sendmessage, для его редактирования методом editmessagetext в телеграмм боте

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас библиотека pyTelegramBotApi

> message.message_id